# Quotient of two sums

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, summation

Let $i>0$ and $j>0$. Is it true that

$$\dfrac{\sum \limits_{k=i+j+1}^{\infty} p_k}{\sum \limits_{k=i+1}^{\infty} p_k} = \sum \limits_{k=j+1}^{\infty} p_k?$$

[image]

Comment: It does not in general. Where is that "equality" from?

Comment: @ClementC. I updated the post.

Comment: So from the update:  the equation you want is merely a restatement of the assumed "memoryless" property.

Comment: I was just trying to figure out why $p_k$ being geometrically distributed is the only way that memoryless is true... I can show that it works for geometrically distributed but it doesn't prove its the only way it works... maybe its a poorly phrased question and it should really say just show that geometric dist. satifiies it...

Comment: I get it.  You assume its "geometric", then see that "left hand side" equals "right hand side", therefore its memoryless...

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3-UFi4T3w7c

Answer (score 3):

As noted, this is false in general.  It is correct when $p_k = \frac{1}{2^k}$, however.

$$
\sum_{k=j+1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k} = \frac{1}{2^j}
\\
\sum_{k=i+1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k} = \frac{1}{2^i}
\\
\sum_{k=i+j+1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k} = \frac{1}{2^{i+j}}
$$

More generally, it is true when $p_k = p^{k-1}(1-p)$ with $0 \le p \le 1$.  Perhaps that was assumed in your source.

Comment: Yes, you are right.